# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginDetails' available as request attribute

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

This topic already exists in stack overflow but still I am not able to understand the solution and not able to imply on my code. I am completely new for J2EE & Spring. I have few queries on the below code. I tried a sample login application. In that jsp form, method=post and in the controller method request method=get. I am confused about this variation(it was mentioned like that in that sample code). If I remove the form:input tag, I can see the login.jsp page without the input box. In the configuration files we need to include the commandName property? I have pasted the console,jsp page,configuration files and java class code.

login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Cable Vision UserLogin </title>
</head>
<body>
  <form:form commandName="loginDetails" id="login" action="login.do" method="post">
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="3"><h3>Cable Vision UserLogin</h3></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><label>UserName</label></td>
          <td><form:input path="userName"></form:input></td>
          <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="userName"></form:errors></font></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label>Password</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="Password"></form:input></td>
            <td><font color="blue"><form:errors path="Password"></form:errors></font></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center"><font color="red"><form:errors/></font></td> 
          </tr>  
       </table>
       </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dashboard</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dashboard</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  </web-app>
```

Console:
    Apr 09, 2014 12:27:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
        INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/bin/server;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/bin;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;C:\app\Riya\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;;C:\Riya\software_downloads\eclipse;;.
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
        WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:LoginForm' did not find a matching property.
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
        INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
        INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
        INFO: Initialization processed in 440 ms
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
        INFO: Starting service Catalina
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
        INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
        log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
        log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
        INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
        INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
        INFO: Server startup in 4270 ms
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:50 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
        INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
        Apr 09, 2014 12:27:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/LoginForm] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at line 14

```
    11:          </tr>
    12:           <tr>
    13:           <td><label>UserName</label></td>
    14:           <td><form:input path="userName"></form:input></td>
    15:           <td><font color="red"><form:errors path="userName"></form:errors></font></td>
    16:           </tr>
    17:           <tr>


    Stacktrace:] with root cause
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginDetails' available as request attribute
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(login_jsp.java:234)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:107)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.spring.login.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import com.spring.login.model.LoginModel;
import com.spring.login.service.LoginService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginController {

    private LoginModel loginModel;

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    //this method will load the login.jsp when the application starts

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView init()
    {
        loginModel=new LoginModel();
        return new ModelAndView("login","loginDetails",loginModel);
    }

    //this method will be called when we are going to submit the login details
    //if this fails, it will be displayed in the same page, in case of success it is redirected to success page
    public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute("loginDetails")LoginModel loginModel,BindingResult bindingResult,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            //spring validation utils for checking empty fields
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(bindingResult, "userName","userName","Username cannot be empty");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(bindingResult, "passWord","passWord","Password cannot be empty");

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            {
                //returning errors on same page if any errors.
                return new ModelAndView("login","loginDetails",loginModel);
            }
            else
            {
                //if the userdetails is validated then redirecting to success jsp
                //else returning to the same page
                if(loginService.validate(loginModel))
                {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("user",loginModel);
                    RedirectView redirectView=new RedirectView("Success.do",true);
                    return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
                }
                else
                {
                    bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("Invalid","Invalid Credentials. "+"Username or Password is incorrect. "));
                    return new ModelAndView("login","loginDetails",loginModel);
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in LoginController "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new ModelAndView("login","loginDetails",loginModel);
            }
    }
}
```

dashboard-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.login"/>
            <mvc:annotation-driven/>
            <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
             <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
             <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>
           </beans>
```

login-servlet configuration file also has the same content as dashboard-servlet file. Previously, there was no application context.xml in the sample code but I got error and so I have included the application context.xml. What is the purpose of dashboard-servlet.xml since we have login-servlet.xml?

Comment: What request (URL) are you sending to hit the `login.jsp`?

Comment: why you have registered two `DispatcherServlet` in web.xml??

Comment: @Rembo- I have the same doubt and I have asked it in the question. Why they have used two servlets, dispatcher and dashboard in the sample application. http://come2niks.com/login-example-using-spring-mvc/ This is the link, I have referred.

Comment: @Sotirios- http://localhost:8087/LoginForm/

Comment: Can someone help me in this? Nearly I have spent two days to complete this application. Finally got stucked in this.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `<welcome-file>`

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
```

That means that a request to the root of your application's context, for example

```
 localhost:8087/LoginForm
```

will be handled through the `<welcome-file>` and not go through any Spring processing.

As such, you won't have a model (or request) attribute named `loginDetails` available when the JSP is processed. But your `form`

```
<form:form commandName="loginDetails" id="login" action="login.do" method="post">
```

requires it so that it can use it as a template to render the `<input>` elements.

Instead of the `<welcome-file>`, add a handler method for the root of the web-app context, add the model attribute, and return the view name.

Something similar to your handler method here

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView init()
{
    loginModel=new LoginModel();
    return new ModelAndView("login","loginDetails",loginModel);
}
```

Comment: Can u explain bit more about the final part which involves the handler method. Instead of login-welcome file name, I need to place the handler method name?

Comment: @riya Currently the request you make is handled by the servlet container because of the welcome file. Instead it needs to be handles by a spring controller so that you can add the model attribute before the JSP is rendered.